# How to reshape the data to analyse paired samples based on column values?

Tags: r, reshape, key-pair

I have a dataset with some information of my subjects. They are either patients or controls, and they are matched by age and gender (not perfect for age). 
The data is organized in such a way that each row represents a different subject:

```
data_ex <- data.frame( pnum = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   matched_pnum = c(10,6,7,9,8,2,3,5,4,1),
                   group = c("patient", "patient","patient","patient","patient","control","control","control", "control", "control"),
                   age = c(24,35,43,34,55,24,36,43,34,54),
                   gender = c("f","m","f","f","m","f","m","f","f","m"))
```

Which looks like:

```
pnum matched_pnum  group   age  gender  

1     10           patient  24  f
2     6            patient  35  m
3     7            patient  43  f
4     9            patient  34  f
5     8            patient  55  m
6     2            control  24  f
7     3            control  36  m
8     5            control  43  f
9     4            control  34  f
10    1            control  54  m
```

I want to look at the differences between the paired groups on a specific outcome variable (e.g. mean_power). These are however also subdivided into different frequencies. For example:

```
power_data_ex <- data.frame (pnum = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,10,10,10),
                         freq =c(0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1),
                         mean_power = c(200,145,357,200,345,173,236,276,233,166,
                                      188,321,423,257,126,236,125,132,164,267,
                                      311,264,401,287,246,211,189,256,122,351))
```

I merged the two dataframes:

```
merged_ex <- merge(data_ex, power_data_ex, by="pnum")
```

But now I'm stuck how I can best organize my data, so I can get to the difference scores of each mean_power freq per patient-control pair, based on their pnum and matched_pnum values!

EDIT: expected outcome would look like this:

```
outcome_ex <- data.frame( pnum_diff = c("1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8","1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8","1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8"), freq =c(0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1), mean_power_diff = c(-56,23,6, -36, 220, 41, 72,9, -78,-80, -23,132, 159, -144, -161))
```

Comment: Could you give an outline of your expected output?

Comment: For example like this: `outcome_ex <- data.frame( pnum_diff = c("1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8","1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8","1-10","2-6","3-7","4-9","5-8"),
                       freq =c(0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1,0.6,0.8,1),
                       mean_power_diff = c(-56,23,6, -36, 220, 41, 72,9, -78,-80, -23,132,  159, -144, -161))`